# ArcCatalog import geodatabase xml schema: domain name conflict

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, arccatalog, geodatabase-xml

I've exported a geodb xml schema "A" with ArcCatalog from a file geodatabase in order to import it into a sde geodb in Oracle. I've created a geodatabase with the "create enterprise geodatabase tool" with user sde, and another user "A" to import the new schema.

Before importing "A", I've created another schema "B" into the same sde geodb, which has the same domains as schema "A".

My issue is that, when I try to import "A" with ArcCatalog, a conflict is detected for SOME of the domains. Since ALL domain are identical, I would expect a conflict to be detected for ALL domains, or that no conflict is detected at all, instead of having this kind of "hybrid" situation.

So, my question is: How are conflicts detected when importing xml workspaces?

Comment: can you edit the namespace prefixes?

Comment: How can I edit the namespace prefixes @nmtoken?